# rsync's "Read-only file system (30)" error

Tags: permissions, rsync, symlink

NB: This is a 2-part question: why does an error happen, and how to work around the error.  (The two parts are related, inasmuch as the answer to the "why"-question may shed light on the "how"-question.)

---

An `rsync -avuz /some/source/directory .` command I'm trying is giving several errors (roughly) of the form

```
rsync: symlink "/target/directory/foo/bar/baz" -> "../../bar/baz" failed: Read only file system (30)
```

...where `/target/directory` is the current directory.

I'm puzzled by this error.  It is true that the `rsync` process does not have permission to write to `../..`, but I don't see why it would need to in the first place: it definitely has permission to write to `/target/directory/foo/bar/baz`.

Be that as it may, in the case at hand, the number of files with this problem represent a very tiny fraction of the total number of files being copied, and therefore it would be fine if those problematic symlinks were "copied to" regular files whose *names* have been changed in some way to indicate their special nature, and whose *contents* consist only of the target of the original symlink.  For example, the symlink

```
/some/source/directory/foo/bar/baz -> ../../bar/baz
```

shown earlier would be "copied to" the *regular file*

```
/target/directory/foo/bar/baz-PSEUDOSYMLINK
```

...consisting of exactly the one line shown below

```
../../bar/baz
```

I've seen something similar done when copying Unix directory trees to Windows systems.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I suspect your issues are due to rsync temp files. Please see http://superuser.com/questions/579001/rsync-does-it-create-a-temp-file-during-transfer

Answer (score 5):

**Issue**

I am using `rsync` to backup my music collection (`/mnt/Music/`), via `crontab`, to an older (hence, sometimes error-prone) hard drive (`/mnt/Music_Backups`).

Upon manual inspection of that backup partition, I've noticed that these backups sometimes (silently, if run via `crontab`) fail, as do manual backup attempts:

```bash
sudo rsync -aq --delete /mnt/Music/ /mnt/Music_Backups

    rsync: [generator] failed to set times on \
    "/mnt/Music_Backups/ROCK & POP": Read-only file system (30)
```

---

**Evaluation**

Here are my system particulars.

- Operating system: Arch Linux x_86.
- `rsync`  version v3.2.3
- `/etc/crontab` entry:

```bash
# /etc/crontab entry
0 5 * * * root nice -n 19 rsync -aq --delete /mnt/Music/ /mnt/Music_Backups
```

Verify device, partition, mount point:

```bash
lsblk | grep -B1 -i music_back

    sdd      8:48   1   1.8T  0 disk 
    └─sdd1   8:49   1   1.8T  0 part /mnt/Music_Backups

blkid | grep sdd1

    /dev/sdd1: LABEL="Music_Backups" \
    UUID="b90047d3-147c-491c-a17d-17763f79a12a" \
    BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" \
    PARTLABEL="Music_Backups" \
    PARTUUID="98425256-c626-41f1-a85e-6f5feaf412d6"
```

---

**Cause**

While the destination drive permissions are OK: I got the same `rsync` error after doing the following:

```bash
sudo chown -R root:victoria /mnt/Music_Backups/
```

... and the partition looked fine in a disk partition utility (`Gparted`), the command-line `fsck` utility indicated that in fact there were errors present:

```bash
sudo umount /mnt/Music_Backups/

## Note: if any programs, e.g. a file manager, are using / viewing
## that partition you won't be able to `umount` it until you navigate
## away from anything accessing `/mnt/Music_Backups/`

## Update/CAUTION: do not run fsck on a Network Attached Storage (NAS) 
## hard drive (commonly sold on AMZN ...); these require special 
## software; fsck will kill your HDD.

sudo fsck /dev/sdd1

    fsck from util-linux 2.36
    e2fsck 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
    Music_Backups: recovering journal
    Music_Backups contains a file system with errors, check forced.
    Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
    Inode 85460709 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize<y>? yes
    Pass 1E: Optimizing extent trees
    Pass 2: Checking directory structure
    Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
    Pass 4: Checking reference counts
    Pass 5: Checking group summary information

    Music_Backups: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
    Music_Backups: 164762/122101760 files (19.8% non-contiguous), 423271337/488378368 blocks

## Recheck:

sudo fsck /dev/sdd1

    fsck from util-linux 2.36
    e2fsck 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
    Music_Backups: clean, 164762/122101760 files, 423271337/488378368 blocks

sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/Music_Backups/

sudo rsync -aq --delete /mnt/Music/ /mnt/Music_Backups

$ ## completed normally
```

---

**Conclusion**

Based on this, I believe that when my operating system detects errors on a partition, it blocks read-write on that partition until those errors are resolved -- hence blocking `rsync` from completing its task.

---

**Notes**

`rsync`:

- `-a` [archive] :  equivalent to `-rlptgoD`. It is a quick way of saying you want recursion and want to preserve almost everything ... [see https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync]
- `-q` [quiet] :  suppress non-error messages

---

**Addendum 1: Notification of Failure**

As mentioned, the `etc/crontab`-scheduled backup *silently*  failed. Here is a solution to that issue (added to `/etc/crontab`).

```bash
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"

# add this as one line (broken here, for readability;
# substitute your user name for "victoria"):

0  5  *  *  *  victoria  nice -n 19
  rsync -aq --delete /mnt/Music/ /mnt/Music_Backups ; EXIT_STATUS=$?;
  if [ $EXIT_STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
  notify-send -i warning -t 0 "/etc/crontab for rsync'd Music Backups failed"
  --icon=dialog-information ;
  mutt -s "/etc/crontab for rsync'd Music Backups failed" <your_email_address>; fi
```

With this, I in future I should be notified by onscreen notification and email if that backup fails.

- https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_exit_status_of_a_command
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449543/shell-equality-operators-eq

---

Note that there are a few issues when using `notify-send` and `mutt` in `/etc/crontab`:

- When running as `root`, as a regular user (e.g. me: "victoria") you will not see the notification; and, you'll need to configure a `mutt` email account for `root` (user).
- It is therefore much easier to run the `crontab` entry as a regular user. I recursively `chown`'d my backup location as `root:victoria`, so running that `crontab` entry as "victoria" is not an issue.
- Indicated above, executing `notify-send` via `/etc/crontab` requires this line near the top of `/etc/crontab`:

```bash
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
```

Execute `echo $UID` as a regular user [e.g., "victora" (me)] in a terminal to get that number ("1000", above).

For details, see:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=216912
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications#Usage_in_programming

With all of that, my `crontab` entry (above) runs at 5 am daily and notifies me (onscreen; email) if that backup fails for any reason.

You can test those commands with this `crontab` entry (runs every minute; "apples" is not a program, so guaranteed fail):

```bash
*  *  *  *  *  <your_user_name>  nice -n 19
  apples -aq --delete /mnt/Music/ /mnt/Music_Backups ; EXIT_STATUS=$?;
  if [ $EXIT_STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
  notify-send -i warning -t 0 "/etc/crontab for rsync'd Music Backups failed"
  --icon=dialog-information ;
  mutt -s "/etc/crontab for rsync'd Music Backups failed" <your_email_address>; fi
```

---

**Addendum 2: Notice of Failure**

[image: mutt-emailed notification of rsync backup failure (Viewed in Claws Mail)]

```bash
[victoria@victoria ~]$ date
  Wed Jan  6 08:48:38 AM PST 2021

[victoria@victoria ~]$ lsblk

  NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
  ...
  sdd      8:48   1   1.8T  0 disk 
  └─sdd1   8:49   1   1.8T  0 part /mnt/Music_Backups
  ...

[victoria@victoria ~]$ sudo umount /mnt/Music_Backups/

## Update/CAUTION: do not run fsck on a Network Attached Storage (NAS) 
## hard drive (commonly sold on AMZN ...); these require special 
## software; fsck will kill your HDD.

## Repair disk partition [accept default Y/n suggestions, if present]:

[victoria@victoria ~]$ sudo fsck /dev/sdd1
  fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
  e2fsck 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
  Music_Backups: recovering journal
  Music_Backups contains a file system with errors, check forced.
  Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
  Pass 2: Checking directory structure
  Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
  Pass 4: Checking reference counts
  Pass 5: Checking group summary information
  Music_Backups: 165909/122101760 files (20.0% non-contiguous), 425759721/488378368 blocks

## Repeat until no errors:

[victoria@victoria ~]$ sudo fsck /dev/sdd1
  fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
  e2fsck 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
  Music_Backups: clean, 165909/122101760 files, 425759721/488378368 blocks

[victoria@victoria ~]$ sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/Music_Backups/

## /etc/crontab entry (broken over lines here for readability):

  0    5    *    *    *    victoria    nice -n 19
  rsync -aq --delete /mnt/Music/ /mnt/Music_Backups ; STATUS=$? ;
  if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then notify-send -i warning -t 0 "/etc/crontab
  for rsync'd Music Backups failed" --icon=dialog-information ;
  mutt -s "/etc/crontab for rsync'd Music Backups failed" mail@VictoriasJourney.com ;
  fi

## Check: manually run Music_Backup command

[victoria@victoria ~]$ time rsync -aq --delete /mnt/Music/ /mnt/Music_Backups
  0:39.91

[victoria@victoria ~]$
```